# react-router router.push doesn't fire componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having an issue with react-router. I'm on the page "/portal/clients//systems//configure", and I want to change the page to "/portal/clients//systems" when I delete a system.

I'm using react-rouer's withRouter to access the router, and I do a router.push, but the "/portal/clients//systems" page doesn't get reloaded. componentWillMount doesn't get fired at all.

Am I approaching this wrong?

app.js:

```
const SystemConfigureAsync = (nextState, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], require =>
        cb(null, require('./modules/systems/SystemConfigure.jsx')
    ));
};

const App = () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/portal" component={Container} onEnter={redirector.checkRequirements}>
            <Route path="clients/:org">
                <Route path="systems" getComponent={SystemsAsync}>
                    <Route path=":system_id" getComponent={SystemAsync}>
                        <Route path="configure" getComponent={SystemConfigureAsync} />
                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Router>
);
```

./modules/systems/SystemConfigure.jsx:

```
const React = require('react');
const { withRouter } = require('react-router');

const SystemConfigure = withRouter(React.createClass({
    render() {
        const { org: orgId } = this.props.params;
        const { router } = this.props;

        return (
            <ContentSpinner loadingMessage="Loading System" loading={this.state.isLoading}>
                <ConfigureSystem
                    systemId={this.state.model.get('system_id')}
                    model={this.state.model}
                    deleteable={this.state.model.get('deletable')}
                    onDelete={() => {
                        router.push(`/portal/clients/${orgId}/systems`);
                    }}
                />
            </ContentSpinner>
        );
    },
}));

module.exports = SystemConfigure;
```

Comment: Your `SystemsAsync` wont get initiated from the beginning, since the new path contains the same components as the previous ones. However, they will be re-rendered. You have to perform your logic in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: it's the same props. Should I add something like /delete/:systemId on the end to trigger componentWillReceiveProps?

Answer (score 0):

Panther's comment helped a lot.

I added the route:

```
<Route path="systems/delete-system/:delete_system_id" getComponent={SystemsAsync} />
```

and this is what the componentWillReceiveProps looks like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { router } = this.props;
    const { org: orgId, delete_system_id } = nextProps.params;

    if (delete_system_id) {
        this.setState({ systemishes: reject(this.state.systemishes, sys => sys.system_id === delete_system_id) });
        router.push(isMsp() ? `/portal/partners/${orgId}/systems` : `/portal/clients/${orgId}/systems`);
    }
},
```

Works like a charm now